# Jenkins for django project, failed build after many times successful building

Tags: django, python-2.7, jenkins, environment-variables, git-merge

I am using Jenkins to running my Django (Django=1.5.2, Python=2.7) project. Everything went fine before today. But now I tried to merge the updated file from git and got failed building, which stuck here:

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables. It took unreasonable long time and estimated running time shows N/A.
```

I didn't change any settings and environment variables. What is the problem?

**PS:**
There is one change I just found in Job Config History. Our IT guys (SYSTEM) added the code below:

```
<hudson.tasks.BuildTrigge>  
  <childProjects>PROJECT_NAME-Staging</childProjects>
  <threshold>
    <name>SUCCESS</name>
    <ordinal>0</ordinal>
    <color>BLUE</color>
    <completeBuild>true</completeBuild>
  </threshold>
</hudson.tasks.BuildTrigger
```

Comment: probably it asks jenkins to take an action while executing something from command line. For example you changed the version of django and now it asks if you want to replace the old one while executing pip install.

Comment: But I didn't change anything, same version, same setting file... seems wired my case.

Comment: "tried to merge updated file from git" what was the change there? try to wipe out workspace and rebuild

Comment: If you provide jenkins console log of the latest build, it would probably help a great deal in diagnosing the problem

Comment: found one change in Job Config History. Edited my posts.

Comment: The issue fixed! Our IT guys restart the Jenkins and now everything is working as expected!